# VS Code remote ssh missing GLIBCXX and GLIBC

Tags: visual-studio-code, libc, libstdc++, vscode-remote

I am trying to use the remote development via ssh feature of VS Code. When connecting to the remote server I encounter:

```sh
Missing GLIBCXX >= 3.4.18!
>Found versions 3.4.1
> 3.4.2
> ...
> 3.4.13

Missing GLIBC >= 2.17!
Found version ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
```

On the remote I load the module `gcc/7.3.0` and confirm the version:

```sh
gcc --version
> gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
```

and also find:

```sh
ldd --version
> ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
```

In `/lib` I find `libc-2.12.so` and find the max version of GLIBC is 2.12:

```sh
strings libc-2.12.so | grep GLIB
> GLIBC_2.0
> GLIBC_2.1
> ...
> GLIBC_2.12
```

However, I am able to find the required versions of the library in another place on the system in `/usr/lots/of/directories/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0`:

```sh
strings libstdc++.so.6.0.24 | grep GLIB
> GLIBCXX_3.4
> ...
> GLIBCXX_3.4.24
> ...
> GLIBC_2.3.3
```

so it appears I do have the required versions on the remote. Is it possible to configure either VS Code or the remoter server in order to get the remote development working (ideally without changing bits not in my home directory on the remote)?

Answer (score 0):

check the linux version from your server, you can use `lsb_release -a`. Then check in the next link if your Linux Server meet the prerequisites.
[VSCODE Linux version for Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux)

In my case im using RedHat 6 which requires a workaround. Unfortunately I dont have root privileges :(

Comment: can you please explain which one is the workaround?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux#_updating-glibc-and-libstdc-on-rhel-centos-6